# wso2 API Manager role permissions to delete an API

Tags: permissions, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have set a Role permission to allow a user to create an API in the API Publisher. I called the role "Creator".  I set permissions for Manager->API->Create.  Is there a permission setting to prevent this role from Deleting/Removing a created API (theirs or someone else's)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently whoever have the Create permission can delete the API, if that API don't have any subscription.

Do you bother an API from deleting it when it doesn't have any subscription?

If an API have subscriptions, then that API can't be deleted.