# wso2 am permission setting : Can I limit creator A can't operate creator B's API in API-M publisher?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

User can use facebook account to log in API-M publisher and they have the same permission.

The situation is :

1. Creator A and B have the same permission (Creator, default by log in)
2. Creator B add a new API and publish it.
3. Creator A can delete the API that creator B created.

Can I limit creator A can't operate others' API?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wso2 API Manager role permissions to delete an API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330040/wso2-api-manager-role-permissions-to-delete-an-api)

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem. So I can't limit the creators only can operate their own API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood you have multiple users and users should be able to edit their own APIs and then edit/modify them. We dont have out of the box solution for that as API Manager publisher designed to all API creators/publishers (within same tenant) to allow edit APIs.

If you need to avoid API developers updating running APIs in system, we can have solution for that. For that you can have 2 different roles for API creators and publisher with relevant permissions. Then API developers will have permission to only create and edit APIs. But they cannot publish those APIs or change running APIs. Only publishers can review changes with API developer and publish them to run time.

[In this article](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-limit-api-edit-to-only-api-owner.html) i have explained how we can achieve this using registry level permissions for API artifact.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's helpful.